# Accessing constant from a VueJS mixin

Tags: vue.js, mixins

I have this component

```
<script>
const serviceName = 'events'

import { mapState } from 'vuex'

import crud from './mixins/crud'

export default {
    mixins: [crud],

    data() {
        return {
            serviceName: serviceName,

            apiBaseUri: '/api/v1/' + serviceName,
        }
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            events: state => state.events.data,
        }),
    },

    mounted() {
        this.boot()
    },
}
</script>
```

It defines a serviceName which I need to also use within this crud mixin:

```
import { mapActions, mapMutations, mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            loading: {
                environment: false,

                table: false,
            },
        }
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            form: state => state.events.form,
            environment: state => state.environment,
        }),
    },

    methods: {
        ...mapActions(serviceName, ['load']),

        ...mapMutations(serviceName, [
            'setDataUrl',
            'setStoreUrl',
            'setErrors',
            'setFormData',
            'storeFormField',
        ]),

        isLoading() {
            return this.loading.environment || this.loading.table
        },

        boot() {
            this.setDataUrl(this.apiBaseUri)

            this.setStoreUrl(this.apiBaseUri)

            this.load()
        },

        back() {
            this.$router.back()
        },

        storeModel() {
            this.store().then(() => {
                this.load()

                this.back()

                this.clearForm()
            })
        },
    },
}
```

The problem is that I always get a "serviceName is not defined" error message, since serviceName is used in mapActions() and mapMutations().

The error occurs in

```
import crud from './mixins/crud'
```

And it completely ignores things like window.serviceName, which I also tried.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution I can think of is move the `serviceName` definition to another file. For example...

```js
// constants.js
export const SERVICE_NAME = 'events'
```

then you can import it where required, eg

```js
// in your component, your mixin, etc
import { SERVICE_NAME as serviceName } from './constants'
```